# R: How to preform "quota sampling" on a dataset in R

Tags: r, sampling, rscript, quota

I am wondering would anyone have any sample code in order to be able to carry out "Quota Sampling" in R?

Thanks in advance!

**Update with example dataset:**
[image]

For example I will need the following

- 5 Abnormal, Occurring on a Wednesday, with Humidity equal to 24
- 3 normal, Occurring on a Workday, with Humidity less than 24

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: updated with example data and example quotas

Comment: This link may help: https://homerhanumat.github.io/elemStats/sampling-and-surveys.html#types-of-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following may reply to your question :

```
question1_data=subset(your_data,label==Abnormal & Day=="Wednesday" & Humidity==24)
sample_1=popsamp(5,question1_data)

question2_data=subset(your_data,label==normal & Day=="Workday" & Humidity<24)
sample_2=popsamp(3,question2_data)
```

Comment: question1_data part where it is meant to subset is not sub-setting the data?

Comment: Plz look at the link in previous comment , stratified and cluster sampling approaches are explained there. As you didn't provided reproducible example , i can't reply to your question

Comment: apologies, got it working with the above code. Thanks!

Comment: If popsamp() doesn't work , use the sample() function instead. You could set the parameter Replace=TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 0):

The popsamp() function is a function of tigerstats package :

```
set.seed(1837)
require(tigerstats)
str(iris)
quest_1=subset(iris,Species=="setosa") #selecting a sub group of data
quest_1
x=popsamp(4,quest_1)  # sampling in that group 
x # printing sample
```